# HtmlAgilityPack - XPath: Select Sequence of Nodes After Specific Node until A Node with Specific Descendant

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to use XPath to select a p tag which contains a strong child tag and place it as the key in a key value pair. The value of which I want to be following p tags until it hits the next strong tag.

Unfortunately the HTML I am dealing with is not my own so I cannot modify its structure to make this simpler. I see several examples of using XPath in this way if the text is known, but in this case the specific text is variable.

Here is the relevant part of the HTMl simplified:

```
<div class="div_1"> 
 <div class="div_2">
   <p><em><strong>Title 1</strong></em> Some Text</p>
   <p>Some Text <a class="tooltip">Some Text</a></p>
   <p>Some Text <a class="tooltip">Some Text</a></p>
   <p>Some Text <a class="tooltip">Some Text</a></p>
   <p><em><strong>Title 2</strong></em> Some Text.</p>                
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the approach I was trying in VB:

```
For Each trait_head As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In content.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
        "//div[@class='div_1']/div[@class='div_2']/p/em/strong")
            trait_heading = trait_head.InnerText
            trait_heading = trait_heading.Trim().Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
            For Each trait_bod As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In content.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
            "//div[@class='div_1']/div[@class='div_2']/p")
                If trait_body Is Nothing Then
                    trait_body = trait_bod.InnerText
                Else
                    trait_body = trait_body & vbCr & vblf & trait_bod.InnerText
                End If
            Next
trait_value.add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(trait_heading, trait_body))
Next
```

So what I need to modify is the second XPath statement so that the for loop breaks once it hits that second p tag with the strong.

Looking for this result: 
trait_value = "Title 1" => "Some text vbcr vblf Some text vbcr vblf Some text vbcr vblf Some text vbcr vblf","Title 2" => "Some text"

Hopefully what I am asking here is possible just using XPath, but if anyone has suggestions on a different approach entirely I would be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Final result:

```
For Each trait_head As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In content.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
        "//div[@class='div_1']/div[@class='div_2']/p/em/strong")
            trait_heading = trait_head.InnerText
            trait_heading = trait_heading.Trim().Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
            For Each trait_bod As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In content.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
            "//div[@class='div_1']/div[@class='div_2']/p[em/strong]")
                If trait_body Is Nothing Then
                    trait_body = trait_bod.LastChild
                Else
                    trait_body = trait_body & vbCr & vblf & trait_bod.LastChild
                End If
            Next
trait_value.add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(trait_heading, trait_body))
Next
```

Comment: textContent is not a valid htmlnode member. Also it seems innerText still ignores the child nodes when used with this xpath expression. The problem is all this did was select the text outside the strong tag in each of the strong nodes and ignored the rest.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Thanks for post updating. I changed `textContent` to [`LastChild`](https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v320/html/509bfb6e-9590-9e1c-f47c-5ab9e416d826.htm). Can you try it?

Comment: I was skeptical that would work. All that accomplishes is to select the text outside of title 1 and the text outside of title 2 into the same variable. I need to select the text in between title 1 and title 2 in a way that no matter what the text is and how many title there are it always selects the text. The titles separate each block. I did modify the original question in between your two responses to make it more clear the result I am after. Also, you need to add InnerText after lastchild as it can't be converted to string because lastchild still refers to the node and not the text within.